# focus: always above the classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, focus

I have a class and I have some validation (no non-numbers allowed (which is not here, but I capture it on the `keypress` method)). However, if I have a class with `focus:`, it is always on the top level of css and I cannot override the settings temporarily. Is there a way to solve this?

In this

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sAT58/1/)

I am expecting red border to come out immediately on the first `keypress`, however it is overridden with focus and only appears when I focus out.

Comment: Change your `a` class to `border:1px solid red!important;` to override the `:focus`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the class like this:

```
.a {
    border:1px solid red !important;
}
```

`!important` will override the `focus` css.

Demo: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sAT58/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Change your css | [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sAT58/3/)

```
.a{
    border:1px solid red !important;
}
```

and script , if you want to remove red border if user is out of focus of input box

```
   $('input').on("keypress", function(){
    $(this).addClass('a');

    });
    $('input').on("blur", function(){
    $(this).removeClass('a');

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the !important statement? Try something like this:

```
input:focus{
    border:1px dashed yellow;
}
```

On JS you can do:

```
$(input).keypress(function(ev){
    var target = ev.target;
    $(target).css({
        borderColor: '#AA0000 !important'
    });
}
```